# Packages for Pacemaker & Corosync for Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: package-management, cluster, high-availability

Current version of the stack pacemaker & corosync included in Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS are 1.1.10 & 2.3.3. Anybody knows of a repository with newer versions? (Sure, I can compile the sources, but I would appreciate to reuse some work here.)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking it too :)
Maybe you can find it from below links.

**Pacemaker**

https://github.com/ClusterLabs/pacemaker

Answer (score 0):

I cannot paste more than two links by newbie, so divided.

**Corosync**

https://github.com/corosync/corosync